# Phonegap Globalization API

Tags: javascript, cordova, ibm-mobilefirst

Team, I'm building a worklight app and using corodova globalization API. Now what happens is am not able to return the value from the success call back function to a function from where am calling this function.But the same works when the value is being returned after using alert(). Can you Pl. correct me if am wrong in the below implementation ?

```
Hybrid.formatCurrencyVal = function(sVal){
      var sOut;

         //alert(sVal);
         navigator.globalization.numberToString(
         Number(sVal),
        // function (sVal) {sOut=sVal.value; sVal= sOut;},
         function (sVal) {sOut=sVal.value; sVal=sOut;},
         function () {alert('Error getting number\n');},
         {type:'decimal'}

       ); 
         alert(sOut);





         return sOut;




      };
```

Comment: call Hybrid.formatCurrencyVal  onDeviceReady

Comment: can you explain with a codesample Pl

Comment: You should add your entire JS file implementation; there should be no need to call onDeviceReady because this is already part of your Worklight application. Simply put the function impl outside of wlCommonInit() and call the function itself inside wlCommonInit(). Again, it'd make more sense if you add the entire JS file of your application.

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);
    function onDeviceReady() {
       Hybrid.formatCurrencyVal();   
    }
```

Comment: This didn't help either Amit :(

Answer (score 2):

The onSuccess callback will be fired asynchronously. That means after calling "numberToString" the rest of your code will go on. So you can't be sure, that when returning sOut, the onSuccess function was already fired.

You should instead do something like this:

```
var onSuccess = function(callbackNumber) {
    // do something with callbackNumber
}

navigator.globalization.numberToString(
    number,
    onSuccess,
    function () {alert('Error getting number\n');},
    {type:'decimal'}
);
```

Comment: Dude, Am just gonna try this and if I crack, I'm wishing you the best of all you've desired, else we can discuss offline :)

Comment: why not, what's the problem?